# PHP's `preg_match_all` functionality in Java

Tags: java, php, regex, preg-match

In PHP if we need to match a something like, `["one","two","three"]`, we could use the following regular expression with `preg_match`.

```
$pattern = "/\[\"(\w+)\",\"(\w+)\",\"(\w+)\"\]/"
```

By using the parenthesis we are also able to extract the words one, two and three. I am aware of the `Matcher` object in Java, but am unable to get similar functionality; I am only able to extract the entire string. How would I go about mimicking the `preg_match` behaviour in Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a Matcher, to get the groups you have to use the `Matcher.group()` method.

For example :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\"(\\w+)\",\"(\\w+)\",\"(\\w+)\"\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]");
boolean b = m.matches();
System.out.println(m.group(1)); //prints one
```

Remember `group(0)` is the same whole matching sequence.

[Example on ideone](http://ideone.com/nQXSo)

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - Matcher.group()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))

Answer (score 1):

Java Pcre is a project that provides a Java implementation of all the php pcre funcions. You can get some ideas from there. Check the project https://github.com/raimonbosch/java.pcre

Answer (score 0):

I know this post came from 2010, buat the fact that I just searched for it, may be someone else would still need it too. So here is the function I created for my need.

basically, it will replace all keywords with the value from a json (or model, or any data source)

how to use:

```
JsonObject jsonROw = some_json_object;
String words = "this is an example. please replace these keywords [id], [name], [address] from database";
String newWords = preg_match_all_in_bracket(words, jsonRow);
```

I use this codes in my shared adapter.

```
public static String preg_match_all_in_bracket(String logos, JSONObject row) {
    String startString="\\[", endString="\\]";
    return preg_match_all_in_bracket(logos, row, startString, endString);
}
public static String preg_match_all_in_bracket(String logos, JSONObject row, String startString, String endString) {
    String newLogos = logos, withBracket, noBracket, newValue="";
    try {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(startString + "(\\w*)" + endString);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(logos);
        while(m.find()) {
            if(m.groupCount() == 1) {
                noBracket = m.group(1);
                if(row.has(noBracket)) {
                    newValue = ifEmptyOrNullDefault(row.getString(noBracket), "");
                }
                if(isEmptyOrNull(newValue)) {
                    //no need to replace
                } else {
                    withBracket = startString + noBracket + endString;
                    newLogos = newLogos.replaceAll(withBracket, newValue);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newLogos;
}
```

I am also new to Java/Android, please feel free to correct if you think this is a bad implementation or something. tks

Answer (score 0):

Two versions, One as List, the second as Array:

private static List<List> getAllMatchesAsList(String str,String p) {

```
    List<List<String>> matches = Pattern.compile(p,  Pattern.DOTALL)
            .matcher(str)
            .results()
            .map(mr -> {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                int bound = mr.groupCount();
                for (int i = 0; i <= bound; i++) {
                    String group = mr.group(i);
                    list.add(group);
                }
                return list;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return matches;
}

private static String[][] getAllMatchesAsArray(String str,String p) {

    String[][] matches = Pattern.compile(p, Pattern.DOTALL)
            .matcher(str)
            .results()
            .map(mr -> {
                int bound = mr.groupCount();
                String[] arr =new String[bound+1];
                for (int i = 0; i <= bound; i++) {
                    String group = mr.group(i);
                    arr[i]=group;
                }
                return arr;
            })
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
    return matches;
}
```